# How to make a left panel in app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile and I am familiar with collapsibles , navbars , etc.
I need to know if it is possible it make a left panel as it is shown in the following image:

[image]

1. What is that left bar called? Does it has a specific name like panel? (I mean the area where there are all the options to select from)
2. Is it possible to get rid of header and footer in jquery mobile and make a fullscreen app like a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hamburger menu? slide-out menu?
http://jsfiddle.net/fh6p4/

```
$('#button').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Close');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
```

This is a google search that will give you plenty of articles on how to create it.
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jquery+burger+menu